# Is it possible to extract feature importances from a KNN model?

Tags: r, machine-learning, caret, k-nearest-neighbour

For tree-based models, I've used varImp in caret to extract feature importances; however, this doesn't work with KNN. Can someone explain why this is/if this is possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a canned command, but you could always measure how much the mean-squared error (or misclassification rate) increases when a variable is either removed or permuted.